# Is $\varphi:G\rightarrow G $ ,$\varphi(a)=a^{-1}$ homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $\varphi:G\rightarrow G $    ,$\varphi(a)=a^{-1}$

I need to find if $\varphi$ is homomorphism, and if so to find $ker(\varphi)$ and to tell if $\varphi$ is one-to-one and\or onto.

**My Attemept:**

$\varphi(aa^{-1})=\varphi(e)$ because $aa^{-1}=e$

$\varphi(a)\varphi(a^{-1})=a^{-1}a$ by defenition $=e$
so it is homomorphism (I think so)

Comment: Why are you only checking for $a$ and its inverse? It is a homomorphism iff the group is abelian.

Comment: In addition, I would like to point out the notion of n-abelian group:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/N-abelian_group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is $\varphi$ a homomorphism?**: $\varphi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = \varphi(b)\varphi(a)$. Here you see that the image of $\varphi$ needs to be Abelian for $\varphi$ to be a homomorphism. So what is the image of $\varphi$? Well, since every element in $G$ has an inverse, then $\varphi(G) = G$.

In all you need $G$ to be Abelian for $\varphi$ to be a homomorphism. As @Tobias mentions above, this is actually an if and only if.

Comment: should that be an equals sign not a minus?

Comment: @ellya: Yes it should.

Answer (score 5):

the mapping $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $G$ to its *opposite* group $G^{op}$ (think mirror images). if $G$ is abelian the distinction between $G$ and $G^{op}$ collapses since:
$$
a \circ^{op} b = b \circ a = a \circ b
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let us check homomorphism first what is the definition of homomorphism?
assuming group operation is multiplication we have.

$\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)*\varphi(b)$ That is the definition of homomorphism.

Let us check if it does indeed satisfy it:
$\varphi(a)*\varphi(b) = a^{-1} * b^{-1}$ and $\varphi(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

So it is homomorphism iff $G$ is abelian you can easily prove it.
Now Let us assume that G is abelian and suppose that we have the following
$\varphi(a) = \varphi(b) \rightarrow a^{-1} = b^{-1}$
Hence inverting both side we get $a = b$, so it is injective.

Answer (score 4):

If $φ$ is homomorphism then for every $a,b$ belong to G $ab=φ((ab)^{-1})=φ(b^{-1}a^{-1})=φ(b^{-1})φ(a^{-1})=ba$ so G is abelian.